# Passar parâmetro a um método get, pode gerar algum erro em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Estou começando a estudar POO agora e é um tanto estranho para mim.  Mas eu gostaria de saber se eu passar algum parâmetro em um método `get`, pode me resultar em algum erro?
Ex:

```
class MostraNum
{
      private:
      int x;
      public:
      int getRetornaNum(int x)
      {
          return x;
      }
};

int main()
{
     MostraNum result;
     cout<<result.getRetornaNum(100)<<endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seja mais específico. O que você espera que o programa faça?

Answer (score 1):

Não,

Get é apenas um nome usado por convenção e não significa nada.

A sua função retornará o parâmetro passado e não a variável membro 'x' porque o c++ prioriza variáveis locais quando o nome é o mesmo, caso quisesse retornar a variável membro x deveria fazer de forma explicita:

```
return MostraNum::x
```

Mas por questões de organização e para facilitar na leitura do seu código dê um nome especial para a sua variável membro e não use nomes repetidos, como por exemplo na [notação húngara](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o_h%C3%BAngara) seria m_nX.